# Issues with rigid bodies in Blender

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

Just a heads up, I am new to blender so try and bear with me!

Recently I wanted to model a chest from Minecraft (dont ask why), and I wanted to animate it using a rigid bodies and rigid body constraints (a hinge). I was going to use an UV sphere as an animated rigid body to open the chest, yet for some reason, (even though the chest is hollow), just being in the chest forces the lid open. Below is a picture of the chest, where you can see that UV sphere is not touching the top portion of the chest.[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening? I have attached a blend file if that helps. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Whenever you are using simulations like rigid bodies, cloth, fluids etc. you should always apply scale for all involved objects.
2. Rigid bodies must not overlap each other (as in real world too) this isn't possible and so the simulation will go crazy -> your hinge object overlaps with your box parts
3. i moved one box part a bit up, so that it doesn't go crazy...and i changed the sensitivity margin of all rigid body parts to 0

then you will get a ...very boring animation because nearly nothing happens.

So i animated your ball a bit so you can see a bit:

[image]

[image]